# How to assign a string to a variable using if else in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

im trying to have my function use an if else statement to determine whether or not a hypothetical salary is good enough and print the result back to my HTML page. .[image: image of my code]

I feel like the code im using in my if else statement is good, but it seems to be getting skipped over and when I print the results on the HTML, the variable "amount" is not displayed, but "salary" is

Comment: Your 1st else statement has it's GT and LT reversed

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that. However, it still doesn't print out the "amount" variable

Comment: Try removing `let` from inside of if-else statements

Comment: and also, if the first if is `< 20000` the following else should start with `salary >= 20000` (or put the `<=` in the first) if that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove let before amount in if else statements and the code will work as expected. The issue is, by using let again and again in if else statements, you're declaring amount variable again and again.  Read about scope of let to learn more.

Comment: thank you!! I thought it would only declare the variable if the statement was true

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `let` from inside of if-else statements because the `let` variable is `block scope` with your code it means you are creating a new variable with string value not reassigning value for the first `amount` variable